# Creating an array from object containing length property

Tags: javascript

I am unable to understand how the following code works. When I tried to print the value of `v`, I get `undefined` as much time as `length`.

```
Array.from({length: 5}, (v, i) => i);
// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Tried code :

```
console.log(Array.from({length: 3}, function(v,i) {
    console.log(v);
    console.log(i);
    return i;

}));
```

Comment: share your tried code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

> `Array.from()` has an optional parameter `mapFn`, which allows you to
>   execute a map function on each element of the array (or subclass
>   object) that is being created.
>
> More clearly, `Array.from(obj, mapFn, thisArg)` has the same result as `Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg)`, except that it does not create an intermediate array.

Now, let's check each part separately. `Array.from({length: 5})` evaluates to...

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

There's a detailed explanation in [standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.from). In short, the result is a regular array with the same `length` value, having each consecutive element (from `0` to `length-1`) set to some value - either taken from the argument object, or `undefined` if there was none (such as in your case).

Now, a map function written like this:

```
(v, i) => i
```

... ignores values (of an array it's used on) and just returns *indexes*, one for each element. So mapping transformation essentially creates an array where each element is equal to its index - `[0, 1, 2, ...]`.

Answer (score 1):

The way [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) works when you provide it a mapping function is to loop through the array-like thing you've passed it and give your mapping function the values for the properites at indexes 0, 1, etc. as our `v` (and the index itself as `i`) so the function can map them.

**Very** loosely with those arguments, it does this:

```
function sortOfLikeArrayFrom(arrayLike, mapFunc) {
    const a = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < arrayLike.length; ++index) {
        a[index] = mapFunc(arrayLike[index]);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Since the object you're passing in has no `0`, `1`, etc. properties, `arrayLike[index]` gives us `undefined`, which is what is then passed to your mapping function.

[Again, the above is **very loose** and tailored to the arguments you're calling it with in your question; see the linked article for a full implementation (the "polyfill").]

Note what happens if we **do** have one of those properties:

```js
Array.from({length: 5, 1: "one"}, (v, i) => {
  console.log(`Index ${i}, value ${v}`);
  return v;
});
```

We saw `"one"` for index 1 because the object had that property.

Answer (score 1):

You should undestrand everything just by reading the documentation on [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method.

It takes an "array-like" object and creates an array from it.
In your case `{ length: 5 }` is an array-like object (it's not an array, but it has the `length` property which makes it look like an array).

So after running `Array.from({ length: 5 })` you will get an array of five undefined elements.

The second argument of `Array.from()` is a map function. This function is applied to every element of the array. In your example this function just takes an index of the element and return it. So you get an array with five elements, where each element is it's index in this array.